# Center align text within an image holder

Tags: html, css

One of my developers is out of the office today and I am trying to get some quick things done without him. I need to have the text "click to enlarge" underneath the main picture of the first to be in the center. All I can manage to do is either make it left or right aligned. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

I also tried using "margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" but had no luck with that either.

http://coasttocoastfishmounts.com/fish-mounts/striped-bass

See highlighted text for clarification:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyr76.jpg

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
.big-image-holder .click-to-enlarge{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```